# How to observe behaviour of multiple AND statement in python

Tags: python

How can I "see" which expressions causes a multi-and if statement to fail?

I currently have a block of code along the following lines...

```
if( carFuel > 0 and
    engine.status == 'off' and
    batteryConnected == True and
    ...etc
    ):
    engine.Start()
```

...with many more lines of business rules.

While developing I would like to be able to understand which of the business rules caused the block not to execute (i.e. what was the reason the engine didn't start?).

I like the way this code is structured as it keeps all the business logic together in very concise manner.

Is there a way that it's possible for me to "see" which one of the expressions fail without having to break up each line into its own thing/function? This is only for me personally as way to poke around and debug things etc and not needed for production.

Any thoughts on how to do this without breaking down and spreading the core logic across multiple sections would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Make a list `criteria = [carFuel > 0, engine.status == 'off', ...]` then `if all(criteria): engine.Start()`? The downside is this doesn't shortcut, which may be a problem if any of your conditions are expensive to evaluate.

Comment: Use a debugger. They can offer watchpoints and scripting possibilities for cases exactly what you describe.

Comment: If it's just for you, add a `print` before the `if` with all the values...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone's feedback. I decided to go back to basics with multiple if statements e.g.

```
if   carFuel == 0:
   print('Car has no fuel')
elif engine.status != 'off':
   print('Engine already on')
elif batteryConnected == False:
   print('Battery not connected')
else:
   engine.Start()
```

While this does require me to invert my logic comparisons it does not require the overhead of additional code architecture like functions/generators. With my IDE's code folding feature, it keeps the lines of code readable and "together".

Answer (score 1):

A generator function would keep the same structure and short-circuiting logic, whilst also making it possible to insert temporary debug statements:

```
def main():
    # do stuff that sets values...

    def business_rules():
        yield carFuel > 0
        # debug one value
        # print('engine.status:', engine.status)
        yield engine.status == 'off'
        yield batteryConnected == True

    # debug all values
    # print(list(business_rules()))

    # normal execution
    if all(business_rules()):
        engine.Start()
```